# Accepting Correct Answers, Upvoting and Voting statistics

Tags: feature-request, reputation, answers, voting

I saw lots of 0 point accepted answers on Stack Overflow and it makes me discomfortable, because if someone accepts the answer, they should and must upvote the correct answer. Or maybe, any correct answer automatically gets 5 upvotes?

This makes me umconfortable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50190833/1944314 a correct answer and no upvote.

There are two possible explanations, if the user upvoted already then it must be someone else downvoted it. So there's one more possible exception.

We must be able to see how much upvotes and downvotes every post has, next to the total 'karma' of that post. After that, we can be sure of the karma of the question; I believe this will be a very useful feature.

I am personally not annoyed by downvotes, but nobody should downvote unless it is positive criticism.

Comment: _"the total karma"_ is called _score_ here, and you already can see it as soon you have the privilege.

Comment: I dont understand the reason that getting downvoted for this question, if i found the answer, i wont ask it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That answer was posted by the author of the question. They can accept their own answer, but not upvote it.

Another possibility would be a user with less than 15 reputation. Accepting an answer does not require reputation, but upvoting does. That situation happens more often than you think, and there are even badges for people who have relatively many zero-scoring accepted answers: [Tenacious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/69/tenacious) and [Unsung Hero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/unsung-hero).

As @πάνταῥεῖ notes in the comments, you can see the vote breakdown as soon as you have the [Established User privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user), which you get at 1000 reputation. If you want it now, you can try [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/3082/34061).